# Why does THIS code work but THAT one doesn't?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, structure

Language C++
Here's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct part
{
int model_numb;
int part_numb;
float cost;
};

void main()
{
part part1, part2 = { 2022, 203, 2121.23F };
char dummy;

part1.model_numb = 12345;
part1.part_numb = 203;
part1.cost = 5050.30F;

cout << "******Part1*****" << endl;
cout << "\nModel Numb: " << part1.model_numb
    << "\nPart Numb: " << part1.part_numb
    << "\nCost: " << part1.cost << endl << endl;

cout << "******Part2*****" << endl;
cout << "\nModel Numb: " << part2.model_numb
    << "\nPart Numb: " << part2.part_numb
    << "\nCost: " << part2.cost << endl << endl;

part1 = part2;

cout << " part1 = part2" << endl << endl;

cout << "******Part1*****" << endl;
cout << "\nModel Numb: " << part1.model_numb
    << "\nPart Numb: " << part1.part_numb
    << "\nCost: " << part1.cost << endl << endl;

cout << "******Part2*****" << endl;
cout << "\nModel Numb: " << part2.model_numb
    << "\nPart Numb: " << part2.part_numb
    << "\nCost: " << part2.cost << endl << endl;


cin >> dummy;
}
```

If I replace the following line:

```
part part1, part2 = { 2022, 203, 2121.23F };
```

with these lines:

```
part part1, part2;
part2 = { 2022, 203, 2121.23F };
```

the code won't work. It gives me syntax errors ( missing ';' before '{' ) ( missing ';' before '}') and (expected an expression) at those lines. Whyy??? I'm sure I've made no changes to the second program, except for the ones mentioned.

Comment: Initialization and assignment are **different** operations.

Comment: what compiler is that?

Comment: It works with c++11 - http://ideone.com/3OUXRN

Comment: @billz I'm using Visual Studio

Comment: What is a version of studio you use ?

Comment: @borisbn Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Initialisation needs an assignment operator

Comment: VS 2012 doesn't support c++11's initialize_list (http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=initialize_list&button=&fulltext=1). Upgrade it to VS 2013

Comment: @ColorDeColor _Initialisation needs an assignment operator_ **No**, _assignment_ needs an assignment operator, and you can assign another `part` struct at the statement in question. The problem is, that `{ 2022, 203, 2121.23F }` isn't another `part` instance.

Comment: `void main`? Seriously? http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ '=' is an assignment operator, isn't it? And I've used '=' in the first case. Also, I thought about it and I came up with an explanation for myself that "Initialisation means assigning values to an object while it is being created, whereas Assignment is when you assign values to an already created object" .. am I right?

Comment: @ColorDeColor Yes, you're right with this conception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate initialization syntax (with initializers enclosed in `{}`) is a very old language feature that came from C. This syntax in its very original form is specifically tied to *initialization* contexts. You can use it to initialize objects in *declarations* and only in declarations. You cannot use it anywhere else. So, from this point of view the change you made is a very serious change. It is not minor at all, as you seem to incorrectly believe.

C++11 version of C++ language extended the usability of `{}` syntax through its *uniform initialization* features. It so happens that in C++11 your second code is also valid. But it is not valid in any pre-C++11 compiler. The compiler you are using does not implement C++11 fully, which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case it's an initialization statement that is supported by c99 and c++03.

In the second case it's an assignment to already constructed object of {..} list. It's called extender initializer list {} and is supported in c++11.

Therefore you need c++11 compiler for that to work.

Comment: Aggregate initialization from the first case is supported by all versions of C or C++. No need for C99 or C++03.

Comment: @AndreyT Ah, you are right. C99 added designated initializers like {.cost = 0.5}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a structure after it has been made. This is because a structure in c++ is similar to a class and therefore you would need to access the data members individually and as someone said before use assignment.

Comment: But I havn't initialised the structure "part". I've initialised its objects "part1" and "part2"